# Add razor cshtml file in azure WebApi project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, azure

I have an Azure webApi application.
I have a WorkerRole class, where i start an ApiController like this:
customersWebApp = WebApp.Start(new StartOptions(url: baseUri));

What i want is to add to this project a Controller (not ApiController, but Controller), which i did, and add a razor view to it.
My problem is the view. How can i add a cshtml file to my project? I referenced System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Razor (i installed razor using NuGet), but i can't create a view.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: why not? Which error occurs?

Comment: The view is not recognized. Plus, i don't know how to relate the view to my controller

Comment: Have you solved the problem - I have similar. I want to show a view and use a mvc controller but it is never called. I suppose it is because the worker role has no iis enabled? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to relate a view to a controller:

```
public class Sample : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SampleView()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

To add your view. Right click in the middle of "SampleView" (the name of the action), it will display a menu. Select the option "Add View".

you can also, set the name of the view you want:

```
public class Sample : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SampleView()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

in this sample, when you open www.yoursite.com/sample/sampleview, it will return the Index view instead of sampleview view.